# MDL animations stop working on copied <fieldset>

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design-lite

I am having an issue when cloning a section of my form (with jQuery).

The code below copies a 'fieldset', applies unique id's and for's, then appends the copy within the original 'fieldset'.

Although the copying works, all animations of the 'MDL'framework break on the copied 'fieldset'.

The code I am using is shown below:

```
//When add section is pressed
$('#add-section').click(function () {
    // add 2 vars to count clicks per page

    // get the fieldset's children that user is on, and clone it
    var $fieldsetCopy = $('form>:nth-child(' + pageNumber + ')').clone();

    // add '-2' to all id's of the cloned fieldset
    $fieldsetCopy.find("*[id]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id") + "-2");
    });

    // add '-2' to all for's of the cloned fieldset
    $fieldsetCopy.find("*[for]").each(function () {
        $(this).attr("for", $(this).attr("for") + "-2");
    });

    // remove the first p element of the clone
    $fieldsetCopy.find("p").first().remove();

    // add the cloned fieldset within the original
    $fieldsetCopy.appendTo('form>:nth-child(' + pageNumber + ')');
    $()
});
```

I was guessing a problem be the JavaScript loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer myself. The problem was that the framework needed to be reloaded. To do this you can use the line:

```
componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
```

Or, if you would like to target a specific element you can use:

```
componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);
```

---

The full documentation is here https://getmdl.io/started/#dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example (**without jQuery**). Maybe it will help. Just rebuild the DOM manually.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("addText").onclick = function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("container_layout_text");

    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.className = "mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label desc_value";

    var newInput = document.createElement("input");
    newInput.className = "mdl-textfield__input";
    newInput.type = "text";

    var newLabel = document.createElement("label");
    newLabel.className = "mdl-textfield__label";
    newLabel.textContent = "kkk?";

    newDiv.appendChild(newInput);
    newDiv.appendChild(newLabel);

    componentHandler.upgradeElement(newDiv);
    form.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```